# Apache Mina constant stream

Tags: java, streaming, mp3, mina

I'm trying to write a MP3 streaming server using the Apache Mina library. Since there will be a constant stream of data for each client would the following code be the correct way to send data to each of the connected cients?

I tested it and it worked but I just want to make sure I'm doing correctly.

```
Map<Long,IoSession> managedSessions = acceptor.getManagedSessions();
            if(managedSessions != null) {
                for(IoSession session : managedSessions.values()) {
                    session.write(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,3,4,23,4,23,4});
                }
            }
```

Thanks!